# Mock is operator

Tags: c#, unit-testing, generics, rhino-mocks

Is it possible to mock the `is` operator? In my code I have logic depending on what type of class it is, but the value itself is stored in the class as the common interface.

Basically, what I want to do is return `true` by defining the mock to be of `IValue`, but return `true` for `is Value`

```
public class Value : IValue
{
}

public interface IValue
{
}
public class Tester
{
    public bool CheckIfValue(IValue value)
    {
        return value is Value;
    }
}

[Test]
public void TestIfValue()
{
    Tester tester = new Tester();

    var value = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IValue>();
    // can I add anything here which will make CheckIfValue return true?

    bool isValue = tester.CheckIfValue(value);
    Assert.That(isValue, Is.True);
}
```

Comment: Does `MockRepository.GenerateStub<IValue>()` return a `IValue` implementation that is not `Value`?

Comment: @ken2k - yes, it will create a class at runtime which implements that interface using the Castle.DynamicProxy framework.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it is not possible to "mock" the `is` operator, `is` will return only true in the following cases:

1. The object being checked is an instance of the type being checked for.
2. The object being checked is a sub class of the type being checked for.
3. The object being checked implements the interface type being checked for.

Your design is bad, you shouldn't require any `IValue` if you actually need it to be an instance of `Value`.

The point is to depend on abstractions and not the implementation, that's why you have the `IValue` interface to start with. `Tester` shouldn't care if it gets a `Value`, `MockValue` or anything else, it should just depend on the methods and properties defined in the `IValue` interface.

The point to creating a mock is to test the behavior of your `Tester` class in a specific scenario, the mock allows you to specify the behavior of the object `Tester` receives for that test without having to create lots of dummy classes such as `class FakeValueWhichDoes... : IValue` in order to test it.

Comment: +1, agree for the bad design. The whole purpose of interfaces is to NOT use the actual implementation. If the parameter is of type IValue, then the whole code block should ONLY use what's exposed by IValue.

Comment: Your three cases are incomplete FYI. For example, `object o = (Func<string>)(()=>""); bool b = o is Func<object>;` results in true, but does not meet any of your three cases.

Comment: @EricLippert thanks for pointing it out, I'd forgot to mention Covariance.

Comment: What if you have `int? x = 123; bool b = x is int;` int? is not int, not a subtype of int, no interface is being checked for and there's no covariance involved, but b is still true. So you're missing a fifth case here.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
public class Value : IValue
{
    bool Is<T>() => this is T;
}

public interface IValue
{
    bool Is<T>();
}

public class Tester
{
    public bool CheckIfValue(IValue value)
    {
        return value.Is<Value>();
    }
}

[Test]
public void TestIfValue()
{
    Tester tester = new Tester();

    var value = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IValue>();
    value.Stub(_ => _.Is<Value>()).Return(true);

    bool isValue = tester.CheckIfValue(value);
    Assert.That(isValue, Is.True);
}
```